# Number of comparisons in merge sort when list is already sorted

Tags: sorting

Suppose the input list is already sorted in increasing order. What would be the number of comparisons in this case. What if the input list is sorted in reverse order, in terms of number of elements.

I think it will take (n/2)lg n if the list is already sorted. For e.g. If we have a list like : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 , which is already sorted then it will be divided to (1,2,3,4,5) and (6,7,8,9,10) parts. Further the list will be divided to (1,2,3) , (4,5) , (6,7,8), (9,10) and so on. Now as the leaf are already sorted we have to compare only the first element of first list to all elements of other list during merge. For e.g. in case of (1,2,3,4,5) and (6,7,8,9,10) we will be comparing 1 to all elements in second list, similarly 2 to all elements ans so on. Hence at level 1 we have n/2 comparisons, at level 2 we have two n/4 comparisons( a total of n/2) and so on. Since there are lg n(base 2) levels , we will have a total of (n/2)*lg n comparisons.

Comment: What do you think? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think (n/2)lg n for a list which is already sorted.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer should be (n/2)logn. In each level of recursion for the merge sort, we need to do at least (n/2) comparisons. Since there are logn levels for a merge sort, the answer would be (n/2)logn comparisons in total.

To be more specific, we can take an example: 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
8 comparisons: compare 9 with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
8 comparisons: compare 5 with 1, 2, 3, 4 and compare 13 with 9, 10, 11, 12
(1, 2, 3, 4) (5, 6, 7, 8) (9, 10, 11, 12) (13, 14, 15, 16)
8 comparisons: compare 3 with 1 and 2, compare 7 with 5 and 6, compare 11 with 9 and 10, compare 15 with 13 and 14
(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8) (9, 10) (11, 12) (13, 14) (15, 16)
8 comparisons: compare 1 with 2, 3 with 4, 5 with 6, 7 with 8, 9 with 10, 11 with 12, 13 with 14, 15 with 16.
(1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10) (11) (12) (13) (14) (15) (16)

In addition, in the worst case, there would be nlogn comparisons in total. For example, the original array is reversed.